# How can i upload to a youtube account specific account using UserCredential revoke ?

Tags: c#, .net, google-api, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

In my class that i'm using to upload to youtube a video files and it's working fine the uploading i want to make something that on the form designer i will have a button of a gmail account when i click this button it will make two things:

1. Will upload the video file to the account of this button.
   For example the text on the button will be test@gmail.com

So when i click the button it will check and if there is already a user        connected on the pc to gmail account and if it's not test@gmail.com then first make revoke then connect to the test@gmail.com and upload the video file.

But in case there no gmail account yet connected on the pc then the user will enter a gmail account it will connect to it and upload.

2. Will revoke.

The problem now is that i have one button that all it does is revoking.
And i need to change on the browser in this case chrome the gmail account or to log in to a gmail account then running my program over again then it will showm e this screen where i need to accept the authorization to this acocunt then it will upload to it the video file.

And i want to pass over the part of log in each time to another gmail via the chrome browser and pass over the need of making accept over again each time changing account.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Upload;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3;
using Google.Apis.YouTube.v3.Data;
using Google.GData.Client;
using Google.GData.Extensions;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;
using Google.Apis.YouTube;
using Google.Apis.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail;
using MailBee;

namespace test
{
    public partial class testing : Form
    {
        public class ComboboxItem
        {
            public string Text { get; set; }
            public object Value { get; set; }

            public override string ToString()
            {
                return Text;
            }
        }

        YouTubeService service;

        string apiKey = "myapikey";
        string FileNameToUpload = "";
        string[] stringProgressReport = new string[5];
        long totalBytes = 0;
        DateTime dt;
        public static string fileuploadedsuccess = "";

        public Youtube_Uploader(string filetoupload)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            FileNameToUpload = @"C:\Users\test\Videos\test.mp4";
            service = AuthenticateOauth(apiKey);
            var videoCatagories = service.VideoCategories.List("snippet");
            videoCatagories.RegionCode = "IL";
            var result = videoCatagories.Execute();
            UserCredentials();
            UserYoutubeService();
            MakeRequest();
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        public static string uploadstatus = "";
        Video objects = null;
        private void videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived(Video obj)
        {
            System.Timers.Timer aTimer;
            aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
            aTimer.Elapsed += aTimer_Elapsed;
            aTimer.Interval = 10000;
            aTimer.Enabled = false;
            uploadstatus = obj.Status.UploadStatus;
            if (uploadstatus == "uploaded")
            {
                fileuploadedsuccess = "file uploaded successfully";
            }
            if (uploadstatus == "Completed")
            {
                fileuploadedsuccess = "completed";
            }
            objects = obj;
        }

        double mbSent = 0;
        int percentComplete = 0;
        VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress vp = new VideoProcessingDetailsProcessingProgress();
        private void videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged(IUploadProgress obj)
        {            
            ulong? ul = vp.TimeLeftMs;
            stringProgressReport[1] = obj.Status.ToString();
            mbSent = ((double)obj.BytesSent) / (1 << 20);
            stringProgressReport[2] = mbSent.ToString();
            percentComplete = (int)Math.Round(((double)obj.BytesSent) / totalBytes * 100);
            stringProgressReport[3] = percentComplete.ToString();

            if (obj.BytesSent != 0)
            {
                var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
                TimeSpan diff = currentTime - dt;
                double diffSeconds = (DateTime.Now - dt).TotalSeconds;
                double averageSpeed = obj.BytesSent / diffSeconds;
                double MBunits = ConvertBytesToMegabytes((long)averageSpeed);
                stringProgressReport[4] = string.Format("{0:f2} MB/s", MBunits);
            }
        }

        public static YouTubeService AuthenticateOauth(string apiKey)
        {
            try
            {
                YouTubeService service = new YouTubeService(new YouTubeService.Initializer()
                {
                    ApiKey = apiKey,
                    ApplicationName = "YouTube Uploader",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;
            }
        }

        private void MakeRequest()
        {
            var searchListRequest = service.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.Q = "daniel lipman gta"; // Replace with your search term.
            searchListRequest.RegionCode = "IL";
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 50;
            var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();

            List<string> videos = new List<string>();
            List<string> channels = new List<string>();
            List<string> playlists = new List<string>();

            foreach (var searchResult in searchListResponse.Items)
            {
                switch (searchResult.Id.Kind)
                {
                    case "youtube#video":
                        videos.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.VideoId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#channel":
                        channels.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.ChannelId));
                        break;

                    case "youtube#playlist":
                        playlists.Add(String.Format("{0} ({1})", searchResult.Snippet.Title, searchResult.Id.PlaylistId));
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        static Video video = new Video();

        public void Revoke()
        {
            if (uc!=null)
            {
                uc.RevokeTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
            }

        }

        UserCredential uc = null;
        private void UploadVideo(string FileName, string VideoTitle, string VideoDescription)
        {
            try
            {
                var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
                });

                video.Snippet = new VideoSnippet();
                video.Snippet.Title = VideoTitle;
                video.Snippet.Description = VideoDescription;
                video.Snippet.Tags = new string[] { "tag1", "tag2" };
                video.Status = new VideoStatus();
                video.Status.PrivacyStatus = "public";
                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(FileName, FileMode.Open))
                {

                    const int KB = 0x400;
                    var minimumChunkSize = 256 * KB;

                    var videosInsertRequest = youtubeService.Videos.Insert(video,
                        "snippet,status", fileStream, "video/*");
                    videosInsertRequest.ProgressChanged +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ProgressChanged;
                    videosInsertRequest.ResponseReceived +=
                        videosInsertRequest_ResponseReceived;
                    // The default chunk size is 10MB, here will use 1MB.
                    videosInsertRequest.ChunkSize = minimumChunkSize * 3;
                    dt = DateTime.Now;
                    videosInsertRequest.Upload();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception errors)
            {
                string errorss = errors.ToString();
            }
        }

        static double ConvertBytesToMegabytes(long bytes)
        {
            return (bytes / 1024f) / 1024f;
        }

        private void Youtube_Uploader_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            UploadVideo(FileNameToUpload, "test", "Testing");
        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Revoke();
        }

        UserCredential credential = null;
        private void UserCredentials()
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
            uc = credential;
        }

        private void UserYoutubeService()
        {
            var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                ApplicationName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

In this class i have this part:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Revoke();
        }
```

And

```
public void Revoke()
    {
        if (uc!=null)
        {
            uc.RevokeTokenAsync(CancellationToken.None);
        }

    }
```

And the user credential

```
UserCredential credential = null;
        private void UserCredentials()
        {
            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(@"C:\jason file\client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube, YouTubeService.Scope.YoutubeUpload },
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore("YouTube.Auth.Store")).Result;
            }
            uc = credential;
        }
```

The problem is that this GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker show the screen that i need to accept each time i did revoke.

Also a problem is how to check using the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker if there is any user logged in already on the pc to gmail and get the gmail address.

And then to decide if to revoke or not and also how to connect to a gmail account using the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.

I'm using the google api.

Comment: change  "user" to someone else and it will request authentication again.  Authentication is being saved in %appdata% its stills saved its not going to request again.

Comment: Ok i found that when i'm calling the Revoke() method in the constructor then it will go to the screen where i can select to what gmail account to connect to. So i select one account then it's getting to the accept screen the  authentication screen. I just wonder now if i can make it on my form1 designer so it will show me both accounts i click on one of them and it will connect to it without showing me the authentication screen at all.

Comment: When changing the "user" to one of my gmails accounts like "test@gmail.com" it dosen't do anything. I still need to make the revoke.